# function pg_catalog.btrim(numeric, unknown) does not exist while creating table

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

psql code:

```
CREATE TABLE ref_lab_cohort_level
    AS
SELECT cohort,initcap (TRIM (result_flag)) AS result_flag,
       TRIM (cohort_level) AS cohort_level
FROM temp_labs_levels;
```

In above code, trim is function of PostgreSQL for trimming but it gives an error as follows:

```
 function pg_catalog.btrim(numeric, unknown) does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround for your question, check out might be useful to you:

```
create table temp_labs_levels(c varchar(200));
insert into temp_labs_levels values ('   ABC    ');
insert into temp_labs_levels values ('IJK    ');
insert into temp_labs_levels values ('    XYZ');
insert into temp_labs_levels values ('Normal TEXT');

create table ref_lab_cohort_level
as
select c,
       trim(c) c_trimmed,
       initcap(trim(c)) c_trim_initcap 
from temp_labs_levels;
```

Ouput:

```
select * from ref_lab_cohort_level;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9d477/1)

Comment: Thank you for replying although i still get the same error.
But i figured it out.
Instead of trim i used trunc function and it worked well.



CREATE TABLE ref_lab_cohort_level
    AS
SELECT cohort,initcap (TRIM (result_flag)) AS result_flag,
       TRUNC (cohort_level) AS cohort_level
FROM temp_labs_levels;